# Restrict access to admin area by IP

Tags: admin, security, htaccess

What is the best way to restrict the access to the admin area by IP in Magento? Bear in mind that admin can work either from `/admin` or `index.php/admin`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can place the following codes into your `.htaccess` file:-

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index.php/)?admin/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.1\.1\.1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=302,L]
```

Where `1.1.1.1` is your IP address.

<s>* For the last line, make sure that there's no spacing between `http://` and `%{HTTP_HOST}/`. StackExchange doesn't allow the code `http://%` to be posted so I have to add a spacing in between.</s>

Comment: This code redirect from admin pages with slash after admin (admin/) and with something after the slash (admin/abc). But admin page is still loaded on "myeshop.com/admin". Is better to use rule without last slash (RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index.php/)?admin [NC]) to prevent page loading

Answer (score 5):

Multiples are handled by adding another match line

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index.php/)?admin(.*) [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^10\.1\.1\.10
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^10\.2\.1\.10
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Basically it translates to if this url regex, and not these addresses, then 403, you're out of here.

Comment: Just reading the documentation: If you specify `F` then `L` is implied.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html.
"When using [F], an [L] is implied - that is, the response is returned immediately, and no further rules are evaluated."

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone uses Nginx:

```
location ~* ^/(index\.php/bcknd|bcknd) {
    allow 1.1.1.1;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    location ~* \.php$ { try_files /dummy @proxy; }
    deny all;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also set up "allow from" rules in the httpd config for the virtual host files.  I would also change the admin URL for additional security (ok kind of redundant with the "allow from"s but belt and braces).

Inside the conf file I do something like this:

```
<Location /index.php/mynewadminname>
  Order deny,allow
  deny from all
  #home
  allow from 1.2.3.4
  #office
  allow from 5.6.7.8
</Location>
<Location /mynewadminname>
  Order deny,allow
  deny from all
  #home
  allow from 1.2.3.4
  #office
  allow from 5.6.7.8
</Location>
```

Where 1.2.3.4 and 5.6.7.8 are two allowed IP addresses.   Might be an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

## Allow admin access by ip

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^10\.125\.192\.50

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^10\.125\.192\.50

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} admin [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [F,L]
```