# Can not restrict IP via htaccess

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, security

I have tried a lot of different methods of restricting the access via .htaccess and I can not get it to work. I have tried both methods on production and on fresh magento installation on new cPanel. Any idea why this doesn't work?

### Method 1:

```
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from 1.1.1.1
```

### Method 2:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1.1.1.1
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=302,L]
```

Comment: What the actual placement of code in .htaccess post .htaccess code here

Answer (score 2):

Try below code in your `.htaccess` file:

If your apache version is **2.4** try:

```
 # ALLOW USER BY IP
<Limit GET POST>
    Require all denied
    Require ip 127.0.0.1
</Limit>
```

And if your apache version is **2.2** try:

```
 # ALLOW USER BY IP
<Limit GET POST>
     order deny,allow
     deny from all
     allow from 127.0.0.1
</Limit>
```

To restrict `admin`, try below `.htaccess` rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127.0.0.1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=302,L]
```

PS: Change `127.0.0.1` with your allowed IP address and `admin` with your shop admin frontend name.

Hope this work for you.

Comment: The second option works like a charm! - not sure why the default restriction did work previously - perhaps some server side mod update.How do I go about blocking the admin panel using this?

Comment: Hi, check [**this answer**](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51811/restrict-access-to-admin-area-by-ip#51823) to restrict your `admin` access for specific IP.

Comment: I did try this before - see my post - none of the solutions work for restricting admin access.

Comment: @damek132, I update my answer please try to add `.htaccess` rule mentioned in answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's all about placement within `/.htaccess` :
If you installed the sample .htaccess,

**look for:**

```
############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/
```

**+add this immediately below it (changing/removing/adding IP(s))+**

```
############################################
## Restrict /admin /index.php/admin
## (IF THIS):
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/admin|/index.php/admin).*$ [NC]
# (AND !NOT THIS/THESE) our allowed admin ip(s)
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^254\.254\.254\.254
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^10\.10\.10\.10
# (DO THIS)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=302,L]
```

This example will allow two IP addresses access while redirecting to homepage on all others.

Tested on Apache 2.4.7 with unmodified Magento Community v1.9.2.4 - works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1.1.1.1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} admin [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [F,L]
```

Comment: I have tried this as well with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use below 
In fresh magento .htaccess file have two below line

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

comment it

```
#Order allow,deny
 #Allow from all
```

add after

```
order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 1.1.1.1
```

Comment: All possible solutions I think I have checked. Need some resolution perhaps regarding the correct apache mod setting. I am using Apache/2.2.31