# Magento E-Commerce website only without using the backend admin panel

Tags: magento2

I want to integrate the e-commerce website of Magento with one of my custom ERP solutions. My custom ERP provides APIs to integrate with it. My question is, whether it is possible to deploy only the e-commerce site of the magneto and integrate it with my ERP OR it is mandatory to set up the admin panel of Magento also?

Answer (score 1):

Magento admin is part of the Magento installation, you can't really 'separate' the two.

I am not sure how you plan to do the integration between the systems (which system calls which system's API), but anyway, you should know that **you can restrict the admin URL from being accessible** at the webserver level if needed (maybe [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51811/restrict-access-to-admin-area-by-ip#51823) helps).

Comment: Thanks, Diana..

Comment: you're welcome!